# What is => operator in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have started working on Javascript recently after a long break and saw a few instances where `=>` operator is being used in many places. Is this something new and a shorthand of something? Where can I find documentation for it or can someone explain? I have googled it but couldn't find anything that could relate to `=>`

for Example,

```
browser.getCapabilities().then((c) => {
  console.log(c);
});
```

The one I could relate to is

```
browser.getCapabilities().then(function() {
  console.log(c);
});
```

Comment: It is an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: Thanks @zerkms for the docs. I get it now

Comment: Btw, "What's the meaning of => in Javascript" search on Google doesn't lead to any SO answers

Comment: it's hard to search by non-alphanumeric operators in google. Even `"=>"` quoting it does not help much. For that very reason some languages implement specific character-friendly search over their docs, like https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/ (which is super cool btw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(a,b) => a + b
```

is the same function as

```
function (a, b) {
    return a + b;
}
```